# Including a php file makes html section not work properly

Tags: html

There's something wrong with one of my websites. If I include a php file to connect to the database like this one:

```
<?php
$username = "";
$password = "";
$hostname = ""; 

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$selected = mysql_select_db("rugbyspi_ador",$dbhandle) or die("Could not select examples");

mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

and rename the file from index.html to index.php one section appears very big.
I'll give you the link to see by yourself:

http://www.rugbyspirit.net/ador_test/index.php look at "Scolile participante"
And here is the exact same HTML code without including the php file to connect to the database: http://www.rugbyspirit.net/ador_test/test.html
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: They look the exact same to me. What browser you looking in?

Comment: They look the same for me as well (using Opera)

Comment: Google Chrome 24. I used mysqli functions now. Could it be because of that?

Comment: This is a CSS issue. Remove `height: 100%;` from `style.css` at line 82.

Comment: I looked at both with Safari. The green box (with photos of buildings) extends far beyond the pictures in the .php version compared to the .html version. I saved the source code of both, and did a diff. Significant differences in white space, but otherwise the files were identical (although diff did flag the first lines as different but I couldn't see what that difference was).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a CSS issue. You just need to adjust your CSS:

```
.box {
    background: url(images/box.png) repeat 0 0;
    padding: 19px 32px 29px 32px;
    position: relative;
}
```

You have `height: 100%` set on `.box`, which isn't needed. This is causing the Chrome issue.